# Spark SQL Execution Plan of Spark 2.3 is too slow

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

I've upgraded our HDP system (Hortonworks Data Platform) from 2.5.2 to  newest versions (2.6.5). Everything worked perfectly except Spark 2. When i ran this query (a complex query) on Spark 2.3 (current spark version on HDP 2.6.5):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A JOIN B ...
```

It took 10s to execute. 
However when i ran it on old system - Spark 2.1.5 (spark version on HDP 2.5.2), it just took 1-2s to execute the explain.

Here is my plan:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project ['count(1) AS total_record#10326]
+- 'SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name
   +- 'Project [unresolvedalias(1, None)]
      +- 'Filter ((1 = 1) && 'co.companyid IN (130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,11,140,142,143,144,34,41,42,43,52,54,55,56,57,58,60,63,65,67,70,72,75,77,78,79,80,90,91,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,112,115))
         +- 'Join RightOuter, ('s.companyid = 'co.companyid)
            :- 'SubqueryAlias s
            :  +- 'Aggregate ['companyid], ['companyid, 'SUM('paid_goals) AS paid_goals#10296, 'SUM('paid_conv_items) AS paid_conv_items#10297, 'SUM('imp) AS imp#10298, 'round('SUM('paid_conv_value), 2) AS paid_conv_value#10299, 'round('SUM('cost), 2) AS cost#10300, 'SUM('paid_conv) AS paid_conv#10301, 'SUM('clicks) AS clicks#10302, 'round((('sum('s.paid_conv_value) - 'sum('s.Cost)) - 'SUM('s.paid_refundvalue)), 2) AS roi#10303, 'round(('Sum('s.all_conv_value) / 'Sum('s.all_conv)), 2) AS avg_all_conv_value#10304, 'round((('Sum('s.Clicks) / 'Sum('s.imp)) * 100), 2) AS ctr#10305, 'round(('SUM('s.all_conv_value) - 'SUM('s.paid_conv_value)), 2) AS other_conv_value#10306, ('SUM('s.all_conv_items) - 'SUM('s.paid_conv_items)) AS other_conv_items#10307, 'SUM('s.all_conv_items) AS all_conv_items#10308, 'SUM('s.all_conv) AS all_conv#10309, ('SUM('s.all_goals) - 'SUM('s.paid_goals)) AS other_goals#10310, 'round(('Sum('s.paid_conv_value) / 'Sum('s.paid_conv)), 2) AS avg_paid_conv_value#10311, 'SUM('s.all_goals) AS all_goals#10312, 'SUM('s.all_refundquantity) AS all_refundquantity#10313, 'SUM('paid_refundquantity) AS paid_refundquantity#10314, ('SUM('s.all_refundquantity) - 'SUM('s.paid_refundquantity)) AS other_refundquantity#10315, 'round('SUM('s.all_refundvalue), 2) AS all_refundvalue#10316, 'round('SUM('paid_refundvalue), 2) AS paid_refundvalue#10317, 'round(('SUM('s.all_refundvalue) - 'SUM('s.paid_refundvalue)), 2) AS other_refundvalue#10318, ... 7 more fields]
            :     +- 'SubqueryAlias s
            :        +- 'Aggregate ['s.companyid], ['s.companyid, 'sum('ifnull('cost, 0)) AS cost#10279, 'sum('ifnull('impressions, 0)) AS imp#10280, 'sum('ifnull('clicks, 0)) AS clicks#10281, 'sum('quantitybydate) AS all_conv_items#10282, 'sum('conversionsbydate) AS all_conv#10283, 'SUM('goalbydate) AS all_goals#10284, 'Sum('revenuebydate) AS all_conv_value#10285, 'sum('refundquantitybydate) AS all_refundquantity#10286, 'SUM('refundvaluebydate) AS all_refundvalue#10287, 'Sum('refundsbydate) AS all_refunds#10288, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'quantitybydate, 0)) AS paid_conv_items#10289, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'conversionsbydate, 0)) AS paid_conv#10290, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'goalbydate, 0)) AS paid_goals#10291, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'revenuebydate, 0)) AS paid_conv_value#10292, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'refundsbydate, 0)) AS paid_refunds#10293, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'refundvaluebydate, 0)) AS paid_refundvalue#10294, 'sum('if((('type = 1) && ('accountid > 0)), 'refundquantitybydate, 0)) AS paid_refundquantity#10295]
            :           +- 'Filter ((('datestats >= 1528156800) && ('datestats <= 1528934400)) && ('s.siteid IN (1026,1003,1160,1029,1159,1032,1033,1035,1038,1005,1040,1041,1042,1044,1006,1047,1049,1050,1051,1002,1008,1156,1031,1071,1073,1011,1076,1080,1004,1081,1082,1088,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1095,1098,1099,1100,1101,1102,1103,1104,1105,1106,1107,1108,1109,1110,1111,1018,1128,1129,1130,1131,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1137,1138,1139,1140,1013,1001,1146,1020,1021) && 'type_report IN (1,2)))
            :              +- 'SubqueryAlias s
            :                 +- 'UnresolvedRelation `global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231_cache`
            +- 'SubqueryAlias co
               +- 'UnresolvedRelation `mtx_system`.`tbl_um_company_orc`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
total_record: bigint
Aggregate [count(1) AS total_record#10326L]
+- SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name
   +- Project [1 AS 1#10410]
      +- Filter ((1 = 1) && cast(companyid#10328L as bigint) IN (cast(130 as bigint),cast(131 as bigint),cast(132 as bigint),cast(133 as bigint),cast(134 as bigint),cast(135 as bigint),cast(136 as bigint),cast(137 as bigint),cast(138 as bigint),cast(11 as bigint),cast(140 as bigint),cast(142 as bigint),cast(143 as bigint),cast(144 as bigint),cast(34 as bigint),cast(41 as bigint),cast(42 as bigint),cast(43 as bigint),cast(52 as bigint),cast(54 as bigint),cast(55 as bigint),cast(56 as bigint),cast(57 as bigint),cast(58 as bigint),cast(60 as bigint),cast(63 as bigint),cast(65 as bigint),cast(67 as bigint),cast(70 as bigint),cast(72 as bigint),cast(75 as bigint),cast(77 as bigint),cast(78 as bigint),cast(79 as bigint),cast(80 as bigint),cast(90 as bigint),cast(91 as bigint),cast(101 as bigint),cast(102 as bigint),cast(103 as bigint),cast(104 as bigint),cast(105 as bigint),cast(106 as bigint),cast(107 as bigint),cast(108 as bigint),cast(109 as bigint),cast(110 as bigint),cast(112 as bigint),cast(115 as bigint)))
         +- Join RightOuter, (companyid#6925L = companyid#10328L)
            :- SubqueryAlias s
            :  +- Aggregate [companyid#6925L], [companyid#6925L, sum(paid_goals#10291L) AS paid_goals#10296L, sum(paid_conv_items#10289L) AS paid_conv_items#10297L, sum(imp#10280L) AS imp#10298L, round(sum(paid_conv_value#10292), 2) AS paid_conv_value#10299, round(sum(cost#10279), 2) AS cost#10300, sum(paid_conv#10290L) AS paid_conv#10301L, sum(clicks#10281L) AS clicks#10302L, round(((sum(paid_conv_value#10292) - sum(Cost#10279)) - sum(paid_refundvalue#10294)), 2) AS roi#10303, round((sum(all_conv_value#10285) / cast(sum(all_conv#10283L) as double)), 2) AS avg_all_conv_value#10304, round(((cast(sum(Clicks#10281L) as double) / cast(sum(imp#10280L) as double)) * cast(100 as double)), 2) AS ctr#10305, round((sum(all_conv_value#10285) - sum(paid_conv_value#10292)), 2) AS other_conv_value#10306, (sum(all_conv_items#10282L) - sum(paid_conv_items#10289L)) AS other_conv_items#10307L, sum(all_conv_items#10282L) AS all_conv_items#10308L, sum(all_conv#10283L) AS all_conv#10309L, (sum(all_goals#10284L) - sum(paid_goals#10291L)) AS other_goals#10310L, round((sum(paid_conv_value#10292) / cast(sum(paid_conv#10290L) as double)), 2) AS avg_paid_conv_value#10311, sum(all_goals#10284L) AS all_goals#10312L, sum(all_refundquantity#10286L) AS all_refundquantity#10313L, sum(paid_refundquantity#10295L) AS paid_refundquantity#10314L, (sum(all_refundquantity#10286L) - sum(paid_refundquantity#10295L)) AS other_refundquantity#10315L, round(sum(all_refundvalue#10287), 2) AS all_refundvalue#10316, round(sum(paid_refundvalue#10294), 2) AS paid_refundvalue#10317, round((sum(all_refundvalue#10287) - sum(paid_refundvalue#10294)), 2) AS other_refundvalue#10318, ... 7 more fields]
            :     +- SubqueryAlias s
            :        +- Aggregate [companyid#6925L], [companyid#6925L, sum(ifnull(cost#6950, 0)) AS cost#10279, sum(ifnull(impressions#6951L, 0)) AS imp#10280L, sum(ifnull(clicks#6958L, 0)) AS clicks#10281L, sum(quantitybydate#6949L) AS all_conv_items#10282L, sum(conversionsbydate#6962L) AS all_conv#10283L, sum(goalbydate#6956L) AS all_goals#10284L, sum(revenuebydate#6960) AS all_conv_value#10285, sum(refundquantitybydate#6966L) AS all_refundquantity#10286L, sum(refundvaluebydate#6967) AS all_refundvalue#10287, sum(refundsbydate#6968L) AS all_refunds#10288L, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) quantitybydate#6949L else cast(0 as bigint)) AS paid_conv_items#10289L, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) conversionsbydate#6962L else cast(0 as bigint)) AS paid_conv#10290L, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) goalbydate#6956L else cast(0 as bigint)) AS paid_goals#10291L, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) revenuebydate#6960 else cast(0 as double)) AS paid_conv_value#10292, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) refundsbydate#6968L else cast(0 as bigint)) AS paid_refunds#10293L, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) refundvaluebydate#6967 else cast(0 as double)) AS paid_refundvalue#10294, sum(if (((type#6938 = 1) && (accountid#6937L > cast(0 as bigint)))) refundquantitybydate#6966L else cast(0 as bigint)) AS paid_refundquantity#10295L]
            :           +- Filter (((datestats#6931L >= cast(1528156800 as bigint)) && (datestats#6931L <= cast(1528934400 as bigint))) && (siteid#6935 IN (1026,1003,1160,1029,1159,1032,1033,1035,1038,1005,1040,1041,1042,1044,1006,1047,1049,1050,1051,1002,1008,1156,1031,1071,1073,1011,1076,1080,1004,1081,1082,1088,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1095,1098,1099,1100,1101,1102,1103,1104,1105,1106,1107,1108,1109,1110,1111,1018,1128,1129,1130,1131,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1137,1138,1139,1140,1013,1001,1146,1020,1021) && type_report#6932 IN (1,2)))
            :              +- SubqueryAlias s
            :                 +- SubqueryAlias global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231_cache
            :                    +- RepartitionByExpression [partition_key#6974, type#6938], 9
            :                       +- Project [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields]
            :                          +- SubqueryAlias global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231
            :                             +- HiveTableRelation `metrixa_global_database`.`global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields]
            +- SubqueryAlias co
               +- SubqueryAlias tbl_um_company_orc
                  +- HiveTableRelation `mtx_system`.`tbl_um_company_orc`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [companyid#10328L, name#10329, officelocation#10330, address#10331, city#10332, countrycode#10333, countrycodes#10334, contactemail#10335, contactphone#10336, contactmobile#10337, level#10338, status#10339, optimisationstatus#10340, issoftdelete#10341, userid#10342, sitenumber#10343, accountnumber#10344]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [count(1) AS total_record#10326L]
+- Project
   +- Join RightOuter, (companyid#6925L = companyid#10328L)
      :- Aggregate [companyid#6925L], [companyid#6925L]
      :  +- Aggregate [companyid#6925L], [companyid#6925L]
      :     +- Project [companyid#6925L]
      :        +- Filter ((((isnotnull(datestats#6931L) && (datestats#6931L >= 1528156800)) && (datestats#6931L <= 1528934400)) && siteid#6935 INSET (1105,1031,1110,1005,1073,1041,1137,1095,1001,1132,1013,1100,1040,1109,1136,1020,1051,1104,1047,1091,1021,1042,1032,1159,1128,1106,1111,1006,1138,1160,1082,1099,1131,1050,1002,1035,1071,1026,1135,1146,1103,1139,1107,1092,1090,1011,1080,1029,1044,1102,1076,1134,1081,1018,1049,1003,1156,1098,1038,1130,1094,1140,1008,1108,1101,1133,1033,1093,1129,1004,1088)) && type_report#6932 IN (1,2))
      :           +- InMemoryRelation [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas), `global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231_cache`
      :                 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(partition_key#6974, type#6938, 9)
      :                    +- HiveTableScan [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields], HiveTableRelation `metrixa_global_database`.`global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields]
      +- Project [companyid#10328L]
         +- Filter companyid#10328L INSET (138,101,115,56,142,42,52,110,57,78,106,132,133,60,102,70,137,65,109,77,41,134,105,34,54,144,103,140,91,108,130,135,80,112,63,67,11,72,143,43,104,55,75,58,107,136,79,131,90)
            +- HiveTableRelation `mtx_system`.`tbl_um_company_orc`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [companyid#10328L, name#10329, officelocation#10330, address#10331, city#10332, countrycode#10333, countrycodes#10334, contactemail#10335, contactphone#10336, contactmobile#10337, level#10338, status#10339, optimisationstatus#10340, issoftdelete#10341, userid#10342, sitenumber#10343, accountnumber#10344]

== Physical Plan ==
*(6) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(1)], output=[total_record#10326L])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *(5) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#10668L])
      +- *(5) Project
         +- SortMergeJoin [companyid#6925L], [companyid#10328L], RightOuter
            :- *(2) Sort [companyid#6925L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :  +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[companyid#6925L], functions=[], output=[companyid#6925L])
            :     +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[companyid#6925L], functions=[], output=[companyid#6925L])
            :        +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[companyid#6925L], functions=[], output=[companyid#6925L])
            :           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(companyid#6925L, 9)
            :              +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[companyid#6925L], functions=[], output=[companyid#6925L])
            :                 +- *(1) Project [companyid#6925L]
            :                    +- *(1) Filter ((((isnotnull(datestats#6931L) && (datestats#6931L >= 1528156800)) && (datestats#6931L <= 1528934400)) && siteid#6935 INSET (1105,1031,1110,1005,1073,1041,1137,1095,1001,1132,1013,1100,1040,1109,1136,1020,1051,1104,1047,1091,1021,1042,1032,1159,1128,1106,1111,1006,1138,1160,1082,1099,1131,1050,1002,1035,1071,1026,1135,1146,1103,1139,1107,1092,1090,1011,1080,1029,1044,1102,1076,1134,1081,1018,1049,1003,1156,1098,1038,1130,1094,1140,1008,1108,1101,1133,1033,1093,1129,1004,1088)) && type_report#6932 IN (1,2))
            :                       +- InMemoryTableScan [companyid#6925L, datestats#6931L, siteid#6935, type_report#6932], [isnotnull(datestats#6931L), (datestats#6931L >= 1528156800), (datestats#6931L <= 1528934400), siteid#6935 INSET (1105,1031,1110,1005,1073,1041,1137,1095,1001,1132,1013,1100,1040,1109,1136,1020,1051,1104,1047,1091,1021,1042,1032,1159,1128,1106,1111,1006,1138,1160,1082,1099,1131,1050,1002,1035,1071,1026,1135,1146,1103,1139,1107,1092,1090,1011,1080,1029,1044,1102,1076,1134,1081,1018,1049,1003,1156,1098,1038,1130,1094,1140,1008,1108,1101,1133,1033,1093,1129,1004,1088), type_report#6932 IN (1,2)]
            :                             +- InMemoryRelation [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas), `global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231_cache`
            :                                   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(partition_key#6974, type#6938, 9)
            :                                      +- HiveTableScan [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields], HiveTableRelation `metrixa_global_database`.`global_summary_partitioned_20180101_20181231`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [networkid#6924, companyid#6925L, clicktime#6926L, countryid#6927, languageid#6928, sourceurlid#6929, regionid#6930, datestats#6931L, type_report#6932, cityid#6933, ismobiledevice#6934, siteid#6935, affiliateid#6936, accountid#6937L, type#6938, deviceid#6939, countrycode#6940, countryname#6941, regionname#6942, regioncode#6943, language#6944, city#6945, conversions#6946L, uniquerevenuebydate#6947, ... 27 more fields]
            +- *(4) Sort [companyid#10328L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(companyid#10328L, 9)
                  +- *(3) Filter companyid#10328L INSET (138,101,115,56,142,42,52,110,57,78,106,132,133,60,102,70,137,65,109,77,41,134,105,34,54,144,103,140,91,108,130,135,80,112,63,67,11,72,143,43,104,55,75,58,107,136,79,131,90)
                     +- HiveTableScan [companyid#10328L], HiveTableRelation `mtx_system`.`tbl_um_company_orc`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, [companyid#10328L, name#10329, officelocation#10330, address#10331, city#10332, countrycode#10333, countrycodes#10334, contactemail#10335, contactphone#10336, contactmobile#10337, level#10338, status#10339, optimisationstatus#10340, issoftdelete#10341, userid#10342, sitenumber#10343, accountnumber#10344]
```

Anyone can give me some ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It may be a problem of compatibility between the two versions of `Hortonworks Data Platform` and `Spark`, must review the documentation in detail.

Comment: As long as you run the correct `spark-submit` function, versions won't conflict